# ImageButton bug in listview(going small on add item)

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I made listview with item Template and when i click AddButton and add item to this list imagebuttons in this template going small.

How it shlould look like
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e8BTXzPDhcbhsRO7Jqo7UB08VRfspcaO

How it look like
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1fHpveogjKiYLYbZE0WsXhRv9_ah50XMP

My listView:

```
<ListView x:Name="ThisList" HeightRequest="100" RowHeight="45">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <TimePicker  Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center" FontFamily="{StaticResource MTBfont}" Time="{Binding time}"/>
                    <ImageButton Source="{Binding img}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ProfileD_Clicked"/>
                    <ImageButton IsVisible="{Binding visible}" Source="deleteicon.png" Grid.Column="2" MinimumWidthRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Center"  BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="DeleteD_Clicked"/>``
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.Footer>
        <ImageButton Clicked="AddDButton_Clicked" Source="button_add.png" WidthRequest="50" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
    </ListView.Footer>
</ListView>
```

My Code of add button:

```
private void AddDButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ItemD.Add(new SchamatListItem(){
        img = "eco.png",
        time = ItemD[ItemD.Count() - 1].time + TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
        visible = true,
        index = counterD
     });
     counterD++;
     ThisList.HeightRequest = ThisList.HeightRequest + 45;
}
```

**MY SOLUTION** I think it's not the best but it works.

```
<Image IsVisible="{Binding visible}" Source="deleteicon.png" Grid.Column="2" MinimumWidthRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Center"  BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="DeleteD_Clicked" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                </Image>
```

Comment: This ListView is in the Frame and under this is similar Frame with ListView. And when i add item from button its adding but frame doesnt making bigger- i dont want to have in listview scrollbar, thats why I add Height(it works how i want)

Comment: I remove adding this height and only last item is how it should look like. rest still have bug

Comment: OK I fix it, and its stupid. I change ImageButton to Image with GestureRecograizer and bug is no longer exist

Comment: please share your solution to answer, it will help others who have simialr issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MY SOLUTION I think it's not the best but it works.

```
<Image IsVisible="{Binding visible}" Source="deleteicon.png" Grid.Column="2" MinimumWidthRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" HorizontalOptions="Center"  BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="DeleteD_Clicked" NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
                                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                                </Image>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the background color property from image button. Its an existing bug -https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4510

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the VerticalOptions of the ImageButtons to Fill adding Aspect to AspectFit, and eventually adding a margin, as below:

Comment: I did that - effect the same.